# How do I install collectd write_atsd plugin on RHEL 6?

Tags: rhel, rhel6, collectd, axibase

I am using [Axibase Time Series Database](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/) and I would like to install the [collectd write_atsd plugin](https://github.com/axibase/atsd-collectd-plugin/blob/master/write_atsd.md) on RHEL 6?  Is there an rpm I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the guide provided on the [Axibase website](http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/writing-data/collectd/install-collectd-rhel-6/) to install the write_atsd collectd plugin on RedHat Enterprise Linux 6.